# PyDev: Can I make the runtime stack shown on crashes look pretty?

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I'm writing python with PyDev and Eclipse.  It's great, but when my code crashes, it prints my runtime stack to the console in the ugliest of ways.  It just prints out a big list and it's really hard to read.  There's gotta be a way to pretty this up, to make it way easier to read, right?  Can PyDev do it?  Thanks!

For example:

2014-01-08 10:28:04,173 [error] Traceable Error raised during rendering process...  - R:\qa\examples\testcases\testcase1.xml 
2014-01-08 10:28:04,175 [error] [Exception] Failed to complete request:

['  File "C:\Users\me\workspace\re\src\CntlrCmdLine.py", line 1001, in run\n    mainFun(self, modelXbrl, coutputFolder)\n', '  File "C:\Users\me\workspace\re\src\Filing.py", line 27, in mainFun\n    filing.mainFunDriver(cube)\n', ' 
 File "C:\Users\me\workspace\re\src\Filing.py", line 115, in mainFunDriver\n    embedding.parseCommandText()\n', '  Fi
le "C:\Users\me\workspace\re\src\Embedding.py", line 70, in parseCommandText\n    raise Exception\n'] - Report.py 
2014-01-08 10:28:04,175 [warning] Cannot process input file.  - R:\qa\reExamples\gd001cabbage\cabbage-20090501.xml

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to Eclipse and PyDev. Somewhere in your code, you catch all exceptions and turn them into such ugly lists.

Stop doing that or convert the output into a single multi-line string and the output will look useful again.

Alternatively, you can try to format the list line by line when you log the error.